gpg erroneously reporting key not self-signed
I am trying to sign another key with my key and gpg is complaining that the it's not self-signed, but when I do --list-sigs the self signatures show up. What's going on?
$ gpg --sign-key PUBLIC_KEY_HEX_2

sec  ed25519/SHORT_PUBLIC_KEY_HEX_2
     created: 1970-01-01  expires: never       usage: SC  
     trust: unknown       validity: unknown
ssb  cv25519/DONT_KNOW_HEX_2
     created: 1970-01-01  expires: never       usage: E   
[ unknown] (1). Me (key2) <me@example.com>

gpg: using "Me (key1) <me@example.com>" as default secret key for signing
User ID "Me (key2) <me@example.com>" is not self-signed.  Unable to sign.
Nothing to sign with key SHORT_PUBLIC_KEY_HEX_1

Key not changed so no update needed.

$ gpg --list-sigs PUBLIC_KEY_HEX_2
pub   ed25519 1970-01-01 [SC]
      PUBLIC_KEY_HEX_2
uid           [ unknown] Me (key2) <me@example.com>
sig 3        SHORT_PUBLIC_KEY_HEX_2 1970-01-01  [self-signature]
sub   cv25519 1970-01-01 [E]
sig          SHORT_PUBLIC_KEY_HEX_2 1970-01-01  [self-signature]


As far as I can tell this is telling me that  a key that clearly is self-signed isn't self-signed. I've tried googling a bit and everything talks about how to self-sign or similar, but I don't see anything where --list-sigs and says it's self signed and some other component says it isn't.
Possibly relevant details:

key1 is a key that was created in this environment
key2 is a key that was created in a different GNUPGHOME directory, exported from there and is getting imported here
I'm using GNUPGHOME=~/.gnupg/onlykey/
I'm using a hardware encryption device (onlykey), I don't actually have the secret key, just the public key (never had trouble with this before, but just thought I'd mention it)

